# Error: "Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to build my first kotlin project in Android studio 3.0.1 . but i got these 2 errors :

1. Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package .
2. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

how can i use or add the Kotlin standard library?

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kotlin.amirreza.mykotlinproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kotlin.amirreza.mykotlinproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: can you share your manifest and gradle ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You set your package name to `kotlin`.

Change all `package kotlin` statements in your `.kt` files to something like `package mykotlintest`

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to work around this issue by adding the `-Xallow-kotlin-package` argument when kotlinc is invoked, that's what Kotlin does to build itself. But changing the package name is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

As error says :

> Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package

You can not use '**kotlin**' for your package name and your Package (applicationId) is :

```
kotlin.amirreza.mykotlinproject
```

So you must change it to something else with renaming or creating new applicaton with another package name

like this

```
com.amirreza.mykotlinproject
```

Answer (score 1):

As @EmmanuelBourg correctly mentioned, below there is some code to do this

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xallow-kotlin-package"]
}
```