# I get a compile error ` Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package` when I run a gradle kotlin application

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I m trying to create a test kotlin application from gradle.

when I run `./gradlew run` I get the following error:

```
> Task :list:compileKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/jboemo/WorkspaceNexmo/kotlin-gradle-cli-test/list/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/gradle/cli/test/list/LinkedList.kt: (4, 1): Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

those one are the steps that I did to create the application:

```
Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 2

Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Scala
  6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 4

Split functionality across multiple subprojects?:
  1: no - only one application project
  2: yes - application and library projects
Enter selection (default: no - only one application project) [1..2] 2

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Kotlin) [1..2] 2

Project name (default: kotlin-gradle-cli-test):
Source package (default: kotlin.gradle.cli.test):

> Task :init
Get more help with your project: https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications_multi_project.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 16s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
jboemo@VONMAC-C02F51B7MD6P kotlin-gradle-cli-test % ./gradlew run
```

Those one are my gradle and java version:

```
jboemo@VONMAC-C02F51B7MD6P kotlin-gradle-cli-test % gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-07 07:28:53 UTC
Revision:     afe2e24ababc7b0213ccffff44970aa18035fc0e

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.10 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.10+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.3.1 x86_64

jboemo@VONMAC-C02F51B7MD6P kotlin-gradle-cli-test % java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

I see there's already this questions [Error: "Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550066/error-only-the-kotlin-standard-library-is-allowed-to-use-the-kotlin-package) but I m wondering how is possible that a kotlin app created by gradle get this error (I didn't modify any code)

Comment: You need to change `Source package (default: kotlin.gradle.cli.test):` to something else. (it's an argument in the wizard)

Comment: This is working, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments now I now that I ve just to pass a different source package in the wizard.

What I did was to create a directory called `kotlingradle-cli-test` and run gradle in it with exactly the same options as before